# Adcolony with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sdk, ads, adcolony

I have tried to include `adColony.jar` file into my libs folder. I can initiate the SKD okay. But when I try to compile the app, I get an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

If I delete the `adColony.jar`, it compiles fine.

Any advice?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add ***.jar** file using Android studio.

In the project **right click**

```
-> new -> module
-> import jar/AAR package
-> import select the jar file to import
-> click ok -> done
```

See the [screenshots here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library/32087456#32087456)

Answer (score 0):

Let me be a bit more precise here. You have to:

1. Copy the .jar file into the /libs folder of your Android Studio project (usually something like /ProjectName/app/libs)
2. Switch to Android Studio and select the Project perspective

[image: Android Studio Project perspective]

3. Right-click the .jar from the libs folder and chose "Add as library..." (last option)

Voila! You can now use all classes from the .jar file.